# Capistrano doesn't use sudo despite :use_sudo, true

Tags: capistrano

I'm brand new to Capistrano, working with an existing server that was previously using chef to run deployments.

I have set :use_sudo, true in my deploy.rb, and yet "cap deploy:check" claims "You do not have permissions to write to '/srv/app/'"

My deployment user is correctly configured to sudo without a password prompt. If I manually run "sudo test -w /srv/app" on the server, it succeeds.

Why isn't Capistrano using sudo?

Comment: I'll add that the existing deploy directory "/srv/application_name" is owned by nobody.nogroup. The unicorn servers run as nobody. But I can't make "nobody" the deploy user. Is my only option to change the ownership of the deployment directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command fails because the directory does not exist. You should first run `cap deploy:setup` After that `cap deploy:check` succeeds.